# Bluetooth folder, different path on different phones

Tags: android, bluetooth

I found out that different versions of android puts the received bluetooth files in different folder. For instance, one of my test phones running `android 2.2` saves the files to this path:

```
/mnt/sdcard/Downloads/Bluetooth
```

and my second test phone, running `android 4.0` saves the files here

```
/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth
```

Is this operating system "issue" or is it set from the manufacture of the phone?

If the first statement is the correct can I check which version of android running, and the point to the bluetooth folder? Or is there a much simpler way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: why you are asking this question here ? Ask to manufacture.

Comment: I am asking, because this is really a problem for all of us working with bluetooth related stuff on android. It would be a **huge** job for me to contact all of the manufactures and ask this question.

Comment: I am working on same kind of thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some hours I made two methods for doing this. You should put the methods in a `AsyncTask` or a `Thread`. So here is my two methods:

```
public List<File> folderSearchBT(File src, String folder)
        throws FileNotFoundException {

    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();

    File[] filesAndDirs = src.listFiles();
    List<File> filesDirs = Arrays.asList(filesAndDirs);

    for (File file : filesDirs) {
        result.add(file); // always add, even if directory
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            List<File> deeperList = folderSearchBT(file, folder);
            result.addAll(deeperList);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This is a recursive method which will add all folders in the `src` parameter into a List.

I use this method in this method here:

```
public String searchForBluetoothFolder() {

    String splitchar = "/";
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    List<File> btFolder = null;
    String bt = "bluetooth";
    try {
        btFolder = folderSearchBT(root, bt);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("FILE: ", e.getMessage());
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < btFolder.size(); i++) {

        String g = btFolder.get(i).toString();

        String[] subf = g.split(splitchar);

        String s = subf[subf.length - 1].toUpperCase();

        boolean equals = s.equalsIgnoreCase(bt);

        if (equals)
            return g;
    }
    return null; // not found
}
```

Hope this helps, guys!

Comment: so it does deep scanning of any folder that has "bluetooth" name ?