# Delete Bluetooth received file programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

As the title says,

> Is it possible to programmatically delete the Bluetooth received file
>   list?

And if yes then, please provide a reference or a piece of code.

Thanks in advance

Ex: In the below picture I have only one item. Is it possible to delete it programmatically 
[image]

Comment: get the bluetooth directory path and delete those files  [get the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087952/bluetooth-folder-different-path-on-different-phones). [Delete file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24659704/how-do-i-delete-files-programmatically-on-android)

Comment: @Developer Just tested your suggestion and it didn't work. The code deleted all the files including the Bluetooth folder. But I can still see the information in the history

Comment: Here is the link ( https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GwHty6j1mSHCWXRbhs3glyk-zYRI5_Tb/view?usp=sharing ) to the implementation. From the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found so far two ways to make the programmatically delete the Bluetooth recent history list. 
Solution 1: (That works) Is to run the command `pm clear com.android.bluetooth`

Solution 2: (Requires more work)
I am trying to use in Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BLUETOOTH_SHARE" />
```

And in the Java code:

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://com.android.bluetooth.opp/btopp"), null, null);
```

**And**

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://com.android.bluetooth.opp/btopp3"), null, null);
```